# After installed all the packages for angular it still show error when I run the "ng serve" command

Tags: angular

I have installed all the packages for angular as per the directions but still it show error when I run `ng serve` command.

> Cannot determine versions of "@angular/cli".
>   This likely means your local installation is broken. Please reinstall your packages.

When I check the version of `ng`, I can see there is some error with installation of some packages as you can see in screenshot.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkzye.png4)

Please help me if someone faced this issue before.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things to try.

#### If this is a new project

1. If you have not already, install angular/cli globally.`npm install -g @angular/cli` Notice the `-g` there. If it fails for any reason, then `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and re-install.
2. After 1, create a new angular project and also check the version out of the project folder.

#### If this is a old project (or angular cli is installed locally)

1. Run in your project folder `npm install`. This should repair your `node_modules` folder where angular cli could also reside and fix the problem.

Are you sure the prerequisits are met before installing the cli?

> Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node 8.9 or higher, together with NPM 5.5.1 or higher.